# Modify headers in Pylons using Middleware

Tags: python, rest, pylons, middleware

I'm trying to modify a header using Middleware in Pylons to make my application RESTful, basically, if the user request `"application/json"` via `GET` that is what he get back.

The question I have is, the variable `headers` is basically a long list. Looking something like this:

```
[('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'), ('Pragma', 'no-cache'), ('Cache-Control', 'no-cache'), ('Content-Length','20'), ('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')]
```

Now, I'm looking to just modify the value based on the request - but are these positions fixed? Will `'Content-Type'` always be position `headers[0][0]`?

Best Regards,

Anders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from webob import Request, Response
from my_wsgi_application import App
class MyMiddleware(object):
    def init(self, app):
        self.app = app
    def call(self, environ, start_response):
        req = Request(environ)

        ...
        rsp = req.get_response(app)
        rsp.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
        return rsp(environ, start_response)
```

Or simple do request or response .headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json' in you contoller

See http://pythonpaste.org/webob/reference.html#headers